# Weird regular pattern behaviour in Python

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have this following program in Python.

```
import re

data = '''component FA_8 is
port(   a : in bit_vector(7 downto 0);
    b: in bit_vector(7 downto 0);
    s: out bit_vector(7 downto 0);
    c: out bit);
end component;'''

m = re.search(r'''component\ +(\w+)\ +is[\ \n]+
                port\ *[(]\ +''', data, re.I | re.VERBOSE)

if m:
    print m.group()
else:
    print "Cant find pattern"
```

I can't figure out why it is not working. If I change ending of regular pattern with `port\ *[(]\ *` then it matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the quantifier is the only difference, then it means that there is no space in the text, could it be that it is a tab in the original string?

I would replace the escaped space by a whitespace `\s`. `\s` is matching a whitespace character, this is a space, a tab, `\r` and `\n` (and other whitespace characters)

```
m = re.search(r'''component\s+(\w+)\s+is\s+
            port\s*[(]\s+''', data, re.I | re.VERBOSE)
```

Comment: Yup. It is tab and not a space. Thanks!